# I'm using UnityWebRequest with C# to send messages through twilio, but keep getting the error "A 'to' phone number is required."

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, twilio, twilio-api

I've tested my Twilio number and personal number using Twilios website API so I know the problem isn't with either of them. Using the below method and any phone number I try as recipientPhoneNumber in the '+1xxxxxxxxxx' format returns the error:

```
Twilio API Response Text: {"code": 21604, "message": "A 'To' phone number is required.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21604", "status": 400}
Twilio API request error: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Twilio API Request Method: POST
```

I assumed I should be able to use any phone number, but to be safe I even verified my number as a 'Caller ID' within Twilio. I've encountered errors related to my account SID and Auth, and resolved them so I know they aren't the problem.

```
public IEnumerator SendMessage(string recipientPhoneNumber, string message)
{
    // Create the JSON payload for the request
    Debug.Log("The recipient phone number is: " + recipientPhoneNumber);
    string jsonPayload = JsonUtility.ToJson(new
    {
        from = twilioPhoneNumber,
        to = recipientPhoneNumber,
        body = message
    });

    // Create the UnityWebRequest object
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(twilioMessagesApiUrlFormatted, 
    jsonPayload);

    // Set the authorization header with your Account SID and Auth Token
    string auth = accountSid + ":" + authToken;
    string base64Auth = 
    System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(auth));
    string authorizationHeader = "Basic " + base64Auth;
    request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // Send the HTTP request
    request.uploadHandler = new 
    UploadHandlerRaw(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonPayload));
    request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
   
    
}
```

I recently created my Twilio account and don't have strong experience with it so let me know if I need to make some configurations in the console or if something in my code is causing the recipient phone number to be misread or not sent correctly.

I call the method with

```
StartCoroutine(twilioSMS.SendMessage("+1xxxxxxxxxx", "This is a test message"));
```

Within the method I've even printed the 'from', 'to', 'body' so I know the method is receiving them.

Any guidance here would be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending an outgoing message in Twilio requires use of x-www-form-urlencoded format. The SendMessage method now uses a dictionary (formData) to hold the form data, and the UnityWebRequest.Post method is used to send the request with the form data.

```
public IEnumerator SendMessage(string recipientPhoneNumber, string message)
{
    // Create a dictionary to hold the form data
    Dictionary<string, string> formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "From", twilioPhoneNumber },
        { "To", recipientPhoneNumber },
        { "Body", message }
    };

    // Create the UnityWebRequest object
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(twilioMessagesApiUrlFormatted, formData);

    // Set the authorization header with your Account SID and Auth Token
    string auth = accountSid + ":" + authToken;
    string base64Auth = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(auth));
    string authorizationHeader = "Basic " + base64Auth;
    request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader);

    // Send the HTTP request
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue

This

```
new
{
    from = twilioPhoneNumber,
    to = recipientPhoneNumber,
    body = message
}
```

is creating an instance of [Anonymous Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) which uses **`readonly` properties**.

The built-in `JsonUtility` uses the default Unity Serializer which has certain limitations (see [Unity Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)) among them:

- Only supports fields
- Fields may not be `readonly`

=> If you print your `jsonPayload` you will find that it only contains

```
{}
```

---

#### Option 1

You will either need to have a proper wrapper type like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    public string from,
    public string to,
    public string body;
}
```

and explicitly use

```
string jsonPayload = JsonUtility.ToJson(new Message
{
    from = twilioPhoneNumber,
    to = recipientPhoneNumber,
    body = message
});
```

---

#### Option 2

Or you could use a [`Tuple` with explicit names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names) instead

```
string jsonPayload = JsonUtility.ToJson(
(
    from: twilioPhoneNumber,
    to: recipientPhoneNumber,
    body: message
));
```

---

#### Option 3

or you will have to use another third-party JSON library that also supports `readonly` properties like e.g. the most commonly used `Newtonsoft Json.NET` (available as a [package via Unity's PackageManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html))

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

string jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    from = twilioPhoneNumber, 
    to = recipientPhoneNumber, 
    body = message
});
```

[See .Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IHREKE)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried all three ways but I still get the same error. It worked for a moment and had me make an update to API url, then once that was resolved began saying the same thing again.  I've even tried manually adding the string phone number to jsonPayload but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Printing the Twilio API Request Payload: {"from":"+1xxxxxxxxxx","to":"+1xxxxxxxxxx","body":"This is a test message"}

Comment: @JMWesierski tbh I have no clue what twilio even is and how it works ;) My answer was mainly based on the fact that originally you didn't send any payload at all which at least is the part that should be solved with either of the three options